# Multi-Threading Console Output Different

Tags: java, multithreading

New to multi-threading and I have come across some questions and confusion. :)

```
public class NewThread implements Runnable {

    Thread  t;

    NewThread() {
        t = new Thread(this, "Demo Thread");
        System.out.println("Child Thread " + t);
        t.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {

        try {
            for (int i = 5; i > 0; i--) {
                System.out.println("Child Thread: " + i);
                Thread.sleep(500);
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            System.out.println("Child Interrupted.");
        }

        System.out.println("Exiting Child Thread.");
    }

}

class ThreadDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        NewThread t = new NewThread();

        try {
            for (int i = 5; i > 0; i--) {
                System.out.println("Main Thread: " + i);
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            System.out.println("Main Thread Interrupted.");
        }

        System.out.println("Main Thread Exiting.");
    }

}
```

**Excepted Output**

[image]

**My Output**

[image]

Why is my console output different from the expected output? Thank You.

Comment: are you sure that you have `NewThread t = new NewThread();` in main?

Comment: The src looks fine for me. And am able to execute your source and am getting the proper output. Are you sure the src posted here is the same as the one you are testing?

Comment: Hmm thats weird.. I have no clue on how to fix it.

Comment: @Jayamohan I also was able to execute this code and get the "Expected Output"

Comment: Running fine for me, as well (with expected output).

Comment: I'm also getting the expected output. I suggest checking that the quoted code really is what is running.

Comment: I copy pasted the code and I get the expected output. @Appsherif check you have properly compiled and run your code. Maybe what you're running isn't what you compiled.

Comment: Looks like a code snippet from the java complete reference (Schildt).

Answer (score 0):

The variable `t` in the NewThread class is not a `NewThread` type, so it never executes the child thread loop.  You are never calling start() on a NewThread object, so it makes sense that you don't see any output from its execution.

The System object is static, and is shared by all the threads executing on this VM.

Comment: The start() method is being called in constructor of _NewThread_ class. Have you checked that?

Comment: I'm going to have to go back on this, after actually executing your code, I get your "Expected Output"

Answer (score 0):

I would think the problem is that the constructor of your NewThread class is not being called. The weird part about your constructor

```
  NewThread() {
        <STUFF>
    }
```

is that is doen't have an access modifier, i.e. it is missing the `public` keyword. That makes the constructor package-private. If your `ThreadDemo` class is in a different package it will not be able to see the constructor, and the constructor will subsequently not be executed when you call

> ```
>  NewThread t = new NewThread();
> ```

I therefore think you should just add the `public` keyword to your constructor and all is good. Alternatively put `NewThread` and `ThreadDemo` class in the same package.

Comment: @Appsherif Can you please check if this is correct and if so accept the answer?

Answer (score 0):

The code, you're posted is fine! I got your expected output!

I suspect that you are started other code where you are overriding your variable "t" with the other variable "t" from your main. perhaps you declared a part of your code as static.

Answer (score -3):

```
class ThreadDemo {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    NewThread t = new NewThread();

    try {
        for (int i = 5; i > 0; i--) {
            System.out.println("Main Thread: " + i);
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            t.run(); //// forgot here
        }
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
        System.out.println("Main Thread Interrupted.");
    }

    System.out.println("Main Thread Exiting.");
}
```

}

add t.run();

Comment: What's the point of thread If I call ``t.run()`` from ``main()`` method manually?

Comment: @user1947279 Not only will your `t.run()` call run on the main thread, it will also run on each iteration of the for-loop